# SQLite3 query to get inbox unread gmail messages

Tags: android, sqlite, gmail

I use this to get all emails on inbox (on android shell or through tasker running a shell command):

```
sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.gm/databases/mailstore.YOUREMAIL@gmail.com.db "SELECT fromAddress || '@|@' || dateSentMs || '@|@' || Subject || '@|@' || snippet FROM messages m LEFT JOIN message_labels ml ON m.messageId = ml.message_messageId JOIN labels l ON l._id = ml.labels_id WHERE l.name = '^i' ORDER BY m.dateReceivedMs DESC;"
```

and this to get unread count:

```
sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.gm/databases/mailstore.YOUREMAIL.db "SELECT numUnreadConversations FROM labels WHERE name = '^i';"
```

And i would like to do the following:

1.- Get the unread count except those in a certain label: `thelabel`

2.- Get all unread messages only.

3.- Get all unread messages except those in label `thelabel`.

I've no experience with sqlite, so I don't know if this is even possible. I've been playing with parameters but with no luck so far...

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your question is "how do I do this?", please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered. Please note that Gmail's database is proprietary and inaccessible (except on rooted devices), and so few people will have direct experience with it.

Comment: Isn't that thing encrypted?